# Requesting data from JSONP

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am currently experimenting with JSONP using native JavaScript. I am trying to create an application that reads data from a JSONP link. Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/29eajsjm/). At present I am receiving an error in my console, where it seems to have an issue with the link requested. Below I have submitted a snippet of my code:

```
function readResponse(resonse) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = resonse.feed.entry.length + ' entries retured';
 console.log(resonse);
}

(function(){
  var src = '',
  script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = src;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  }) ();
```

Either I'm missing something out or I'm doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a callback method for jsonp request else it will throw a syntax error. when i run it i checked the response object does not have a feed property

```
resonse.feed is undefined.
```

It has the marker property. I tried below and it started working.

```
window.readResponse = function(resonse) {
    console.log(resonse);
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = resonse.markers.length + ' entries retured';
  console.log(resonse);
};

(function(){
  var src = "http://digitaslbi-id-test.herokuapp.com/bus-stops?northEast=51.52783450,-0.04076115&southWest=51.51560467,-0.10225884&callback=readResponse"
  ;
    var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}) ();
```

Comment: Setting the `async` property is unnecessary, as that’s the default behaviour for script elements created from JS.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint returns pure JSON. Your browser will most likely complain about a syntax error (parsing the opening brace as start of a block statement), and `readResponse` is never invoked

This specific endpoint supports JSONP by appending a “callback” parameter. In your case that would be `&callback=readResponse`